# How to add to an arraylist without creating an embedded array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, objectinputstream

I know arraylist has a .add() method, but for some reason, whenever I add to my prexisting arraylist, I end up getting an embedded array.... I have a method that returns an objectInputstream, which could be one or more objects and depending on a conditional, I wanted to add to it and present it to the user, however, it's embedding the objectInputstream as an array.

For example:

```
1. [item1]
2. [item1, item2]
3. [[item1, item2], item3]
4. [[[item1, item2], item3], item4]
```

It keeps going like this. I'd prefer if it was more like this:

```
[item1, item2, item3, item4]
```

Comment: Please show us the code that's producing these results.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You're adding ArrayList to ArrayList. The solution: **STOP DOING THAT**. If you want more specific help, I agree with the others: please show your offending code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you are using `ArrayList.add()` method instead of `ArrayList.addAll()` method. The add() method adds the object passed on to the list, where as addAll takes a collection, and adds each element in that collection to the list- which is what you want.

---

Another issue to note is, you probably are not using generics. That could have avoided this error completely.

### I have the sample code for your convenience in this [online Java compiler IDE](https://www.codiva.io/p/1c9a304e-975e-4a55-b968-38530d50a2ce).

As a side note, in the future when asking programming questions, embed a small sample of the relevant code in an online IDE like [codiva](https://www.codiva.io) or [ideone](https://ideone.com/), to help those who want to answer.

Comment: Hey thanks, since I was expecting multiple objects, I'm just using List<Object>, is that bad?

I also didn't want to share code, because I wanted to have a conceptual understanding and didn't want the code to be out there for potential cheating, because it takes a while to strip down.

Comment: First, did my solution work?

As for List<Object>, there are some scenarios when this will be required, but for most of the cases you might be able to do something better.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. I tried using .addAll and same endcase, but I did try specifying to a <String> and it worked perfectly, any idea why? I was really hoping to accept any Object

Comment: At this point, I can help only if I can see the code. Create a small program that demonstrates your issue and share here

Answer (score -1):

Please show your code. Also, please run this code to see how one should add an value to an array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class myArrayList {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);

   arrlist.add(4);
   arrlist.add(9);
   arrlist.add(34);
   arrlist.add(42);


   for (Integer number : arrlist) {
   System.out.println("Number = " + number);
   }  
   }
}
```

This is an example from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add_index.htm

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what you have is exactly what I'm currently doing.